# Can't open Javafx window until I open Javafx viewpart

Tags: eclipse-plugin, javafx-2, javafx

I am using e(fx)clipse in an eclipse plugin. I'd like to have all my viewparts in SWT, but popup a fullscreen video in Javafx. When I do this I get a

> "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized".

If, however, I open a Javafx viewpart first then my SWT panel pops up a fullscreen Javafx window, I don't get an error.

A workaround to my problem is temporarily open and close a Javafx viewpart, then open the video, but then I get an annoying flicker of a window before the video plays. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post some code? The call of the video and your workaround could help to solve this.